# Can I restrict access to properties with Memgraph database?

Tags: memgraphdb

I see that you have documentation about the [Label-based access control](https://memgraph.com/docs/memgraph/reference-guide/security#label-based-access-control) as an Enterprise feature of Memgraph. I notice that there is label/type based security, but is there a way to restrict access to properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment, only label based access control is supported, and this means that there is no way of defining a property control, not even in the Enterprise version of Memgraph.